# Is it possible to extend my "computer" partition?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

I was trying to dual boot Ubuntu in my laptop, and as I have 2 drives (SSD - 128GB AND HDD - 1 TB) and as my ssd contained my windows, I wanted to get Ubuntu running in my HDD, so I tried making partitions but the Ubuntu installations did not allow me to resize my HDD but only my SSD. So I clicked on the side by side with windows and got it installed in an partition in my HDD.

But I realized that, that partition was only 40 GB in space, but I have around 700 GB free, so is there any way I could increase my Linux partition?

[This is my HDD, as you can see I have partitioned my HDD into a 150 GB as well, thinking I could use this to extend my "computer"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LoPMc.png)

[This is my computer partition which I want to extend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdcwI.png)

I also have a snap space of 13 GB, but have a ram of 12 GB, so is there a way of extending that too?

Answer (score 0):

### Extend computer Partition

You should boot from a Live USB, not the OS whose partition is being worked on.

- Open GParted, select the HDD from the dropdown upper right.
- Right click the 150GB partition and select `Delete`.
- Click the green `Apply` check mark.
- Right click the 40GB partition and select Resize/Move.
- Stretch the partition to fill the empty space, leaving 1GB on the right to increase the swap space. Stretch the swap to fill the space.
- Click the green `Apply` check mark.